# Trying to create a whois in python but it doesn't run

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, whois

For some reason, the output returns like this instead of how it should be: Listed; one under the other; organized.

**Reference:**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkKDZ.png]

**consulta.py**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from sys import argv
import pyfiglet

ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("WHOIS - Gustang")
print (ascii_banner)

host = 'whois.iana.org'
port = 43
conn = host, port
crlf = b'\r\n'
bufsiz = 2172

if len(argv) == 2:

        with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                s.connect(conn)
                ba = bytearray()
                ba.endswith(crlf)
                s.send(f'{argv[1]}\r\n'.encode())
                resp = s.recv(bufsiz)
                print (resp)
```

Comment: Are you sure it hangs?  It could be waiting on a timeout on the socket operations.  Add a couple print statements in your code to see exactly where it hangs.

Comment: I achieved. However, it does not read /r/n as it should, here is the print: (https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/0nHL1XM)

Comment: You should put extra details in the question, cut-paste the text in here.  I will not click on external links (.br ?  Brazil?)

Comment: Yes I'm brazilian. I edited the post code to what worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your output looks to be raw bytes (notice the b in front). The `recv` returns the raw bytes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv
My guess would be that casting it to a string `print(resp.decode("utf-8"))` will render the "\r\n" correctly.
See [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)